# Python: Import other python files while running from web interface

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I am running python scripts called from php in an apache server. If I want to import a python file from the same / a different folder, how to do that? My apache server is running in one directory, but the python code is in a different directory. So how can I relate these two dir structures?

**I have commonly using variables with values in the file to be imported(say file2.py).**

```
+ apacheFolder
| folder1
| +folder2
  |- index.html
  |+ pythonFileDir
     |-__init__.py
     |-file1.py
     |-file2.py
     |-file3.py
```

I tried doing following import command in `file1.py`,

```
import file2
```

But this doesn't help me.
I am calling file1.py from the php file as,

```
shell_exec("[pythonInstallDir]/python.exe [pythonFileDir]/file1.py arg1 arg2");
```

This php is in turn called by html form action trigger.

Comment: How do you call `file1.py` in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an `__init__.py` in the `pythonFileDir` first and try again.  Depending on where you are initially calling `file1.py` from might alter how `file2.py` is called as well.  You may need to call `file2.py` with `from pythonFileDir import file2`

The reason why `file1.py` is called but can't find `file2.py` is due to how the `file1.py` is being called.

```
shell_exec("[pythonInstallDir]/python.exe [pythonFileDir]/file1.py arg1 arg2");
```

`file1.py` will try to find `file2.py` from the same directory that executes your `shell_exec` (most likely the PHP path or the web directory in which it is called from) so `file2.py` is being searched for in a completely different directory (far away from `pythonFileDir`).

You could try to change your directory with the `shell_exec` call with this:

```
shell_exec("cd [pythonFileDir]; [pythonInstallDir]/python.exe file1.py arg1 arg2");
```

That way you will actually be executing from inside the `pythonFileDir` and there won't be any problem finding `file2.py`

So a full example would be:

shell_exec("cd c:\path\to\pythonFileDir; [pythonInstallDir]/python.exe file1.py arg1 arg2");

or you could try this to force PHP to change the directory instead of doing it all within the `shell_exec()` command:

```
chdir( 'C:\path\to\pythonFileDir' );
shell_exec("[pythonInstallDir]/python.exe file1.py arg1 arg2");
```

Comment: I have tried the same also. It is not working. I have updated that file also in my question.

Comment: please provide the method that is initially calling `file1.py` and indicate which directory it is in.

Comment: I've updated my question by explaining my way of calling

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution that should work for you by changing into the directory in which your Python code resides.

Comment: Yeah this approach is an easy one. @Ashwin - did this work for you? Please accept the answer or let us continue to help you.

Comment: This is not working. I tried the following line,  `echo shell_exec ("cd pythonDir ; $pythonExe file1.py arg1 arg2")`

Comment: That won't work unless `pythonDir` is in the directory that `shell_exec` executes commands from which is unlikely.  It will have to be more like `shell_exec("cd c:\\path\\to\\pythonFilesDir; $pythonExe file1.py arg1 arg2")`

Comment: I used the same way you directed above. But its not working. Have you tried doing the same ? If yes please share the exact code

Comment: I just added to my answer another way to change the directory by getting PHP to change the directory first before the `shell_exec` call is made.

Answer (score 0):

As @sth asked and Max Worg already mentioned. I'm not sure how you call the file1.py from php but you could try adding the python directory to your python path?

In file1.py

```
import sys
# either absolute or relative path to pythonFolderDir in file1.py
sys.path.append('/home/user/apacheFolder/folder2/pythonFolderDir');
import file2.py
```

I don't think this is a good idea but that'd be one way to relate your directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the webserver by implementing socket in Python. You have a class that spawns a thread that is a listener, and a thread that holds the other python objects. From there, you can have the object thread re-import when it detects changes in the files in the directory that you can specify in the class. You just put a while loop in there that uses os.listdir, and you can either hash the files, or just see if they simply increase, that is up to you. Now you have something that can communicate over the network, and that reloads modules for you.